# Swiper Element with parameter as props doesn't allow navigaiton-next-el

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js

I try to add custom next and prev button using swiper element and parameters as attributes:

```
<swiper-container
  navigation="true"
  navigation-next-el=".next-el"
  navigation-prev-el=".prev-el"
>
  <swiper-slide>
    Slide1
  </swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>
    Slide2
  </swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>
    Slide3
  </swiper-slide>
  <button class="prev-el">PREV</button>
  <button class="next-el">NEXT</button>
</swiper-container>
```

But actually there is this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'nextEl' on string 'true'`

I don't understand where does this came from, in my script I simply have this:

```
import { register } from "swiper/element/bundle"

register()
```

I tried everything even working with parameters as props but it result on more errors, if you have a solution thank you :)

**EDIT with answer**

Here is how I solved it

```
<div>
    <swiper-container
      :navigation="{
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      }"
    >
      <swiper-slide>
        Slide1
      </swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>
        Slide2
      </swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>
        Slide3
      </swiper-slide>
    </swiper-container>
    <button type="button" class="swiper-button-next">NEXT</button>
    <button type="button" class="swiper-button-prev">PREV</button>
  </div>
```